# Button with <i> making table row disappear

Tags: html, button, font-awesome, gentelella

I am using the template Gentelella Alela but seem to have a tiny problem. I am using a `table` to display products from a `database table`. Each `row` has a `button` to load up a new `page` to edit that specific product.

This is working correctly, however when I press on the `button`. That `row` in the `table` disappears (The `row` comes back as normal when I return back to the page). I have narrowed it down that the problem is the `<i>` tag as when I remove the `button` and keep the `<i>`, the rows are disappearing.

I am unsure on how to fix this, does anyone have any suggestions? I haven't added any custom `scripts` or `css` to the template. This is the current code on the `table`. If anything else is required, I will try to help.

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SKU</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
      <th>Alternative Code (Barcode)</th>
      <th>#Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $product->ProdCode; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $product->Description; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product->AlternativeCode; ?></td>
        <td>
          <form id="view_product_form" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('main/view_product')?>" novalidate>
            <input type="hidden" name="sku" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $product->ProdCode;?>">
            <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></center>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have same ID for every product iteration, that is wrong.

Comment: Hi @Justinas, I have altered this. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Try adding ***display:inline-block*** to the button

Comment: Hi @DanWhite thanks for your help, but the problem still exists (Whole Row of selected product disappearing).